# MIPS "Bad FP value:"

Tags: registry, mips, simulator, mips32, qtspim

Excuse me, I'm using QTSpim simulator, and when I'm trying to modify the FG3 register contend to -5,4 I get this message

**Bad FP value:-5,4**

and I need to specifically enter that value,a help is appreciated.

Comment: What is "-5,4" supposed to be? Do you mean -5.4?

Comment: @Michael -5,4 is the value that I want to introduce in the  FG3  registrer

Comment: My point was that you probably want a decimal _point_ rather than a decimal _comma_.

Comment: @ Michael putting him with comma or point me get this:
**Bad FP value: -5.4 or -5.4**

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the exact code that you're trying to assemble.

Comment: @ Michael   .data
midato1:
 .word 0xA2B1C3E0
micadena:
 .asciiz "\nMIPS Assembly Language example.\n"
 .text
main: 
 la $t0,midato1 #midato1: direccion 0x10010024
 lbu $t1,($t0) # Load in the register t1 unsigned byte located at the address stored in $ t0
 lw $a0,($t0)
 li $v0,1
 syscall # Print the whole saved my data1
 la $a0,micadena #micadena: address
 li $v0,4
 syscall #Prints on the console the string pointed to by stereo
 li $v0,10
 syscall

Comment: Add the code to your question as an [edit], don't post it in a comment.